# I am getting a 'Callback is undefined error' in d3

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I'm working with d3 v5.

I am getting a "callback is undefined "error. I am trying to create a line chart that visualizes the number of game ratings. The x axis is supposed to show a label every three months whereas the y axis should show the number of ratings.

Error screenshot:

[image: error screenshot shown here]

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
   <style>

/* CSS Styling */
.line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ffab00;
   stroke-width: 3;
}

.overlay {
 fill: none;
 pointer-events: all;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
   fill: #ffab00;
   stroke: #fff;
}

.focus circle {
 fill: none;
 stroke: steelblue;
}

   </style>
</head>
<!-- Body tag is where we will append our SVG and SVG objects-->
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.16.0/dist/d3.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 70},
   width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%b %y")

// set the ranges
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
//x.ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(5)).map(formatTime)

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

// Create a line generator
var line = d3.line()
.x(function(d){
   return xScale(d.date);
})

.y(function(d){
   return yScale(d.running_total);
})


var svgElement = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
   .attr("transform",
         "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv").then(function(data) {

 // format the data
 data.forEach(function(d) {
     d.date = parseTime(d.date)
     console.log("date", d.date)
     d.close = +d.close;
 });

 // Scale the range of the data
 xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
 yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

 var path = svgElement.append("path")
 .attr("d", line(data));

 // Add the x Axis
 var xAxis = svgElement.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis)
       .ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(3))
       .tickFormat(formatTime);

 // Add the y Axis
 var yAxis = svgElement.append("g")
     .call(yAxis);

});


</script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called the wrong object, instead of calling the `xAxis` and `yAxis` themselves, you should call axis generators.

```
 // Add the x Axis
 var xAxis = svgElement.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
         .ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(3))
         .tickFormat(formatTime));

 // Add the y Axis
 var yAxis = svgElement.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

 });
```

See more in [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis)